# android custom markers with a transparent Bus image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to add a transparent bus marker to my Google MAP, But it doesn't add the way i wanted as show in pic,[GoodOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9JmN.png)

image that i use for marker

But this what i get [thisiswhatiget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlxx8.png)

Also it doesn't take bus exact shape but it draws in Rectangle format

here is my code from main activity

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bus);
               Bitmap circle = getCircleBitmap(image, 80);
               Marker mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(circle))
                    .flat(true).anchor(0.25f, 0.25f)
                    .visible(true)
                    .position(position));

 public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int size){
      Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bmp, 50, 50);
      Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size,     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    int color = Color.RED;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, size, size);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(thumbnail, 15,15, paint);

    //thumbnail.recycle();
    return output;
  }
```

Please do help on this, Is it that BITMAP makes picture loose transparency?

Comment: why dont you use a white bitmap? i am not sure if transparent is possible here

Comment: I need to get rid of that rectangle shape in which Bus image was shown first.. but i am not finding a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drawable (`bus.png` for example) has a transparent background (this is very important and according to your result I think that it has a white background), you just need to change the `PorterDuff` mode to be `SRC_OVER` in your `getCircleBitmap`:

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
```

Comment: I have tried changing setXfermode but it didn't work, My image is still not transparent paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));

Comment: Does your png have transparent background?

Comment: yes, here is the link. was it my RectF rectF = new RectF(rect); causing problem??  http://filebin.ca/2rmXYpo9ECDe/bus.png

Comment: Sorry my bad its the problem with image, i tried with  http://filebin.ca/2rmbgEG4SXJZ/busicon.png and it worked well.. thanks you for your help :)